# Как развернуть таблицу с PIVOT?

Tags: mysql

Ранее пытался решить вопрос, но кажется сложноватым c LEFT JOIN

```
SELECT c.CountryName, cc.CityName FROM country as c  
LEFT JOIN citytocountry as cc ON (c.idCountry = cc.CountryId) AND (c.CountryName LIKE 'a%') 
GROUP BY c.CountryName, cc.CityName ORDER BY c.CountryName DESC
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сделал вот так:

```
SELECT c.CountryName, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(cc.id,'~',cc.CityName))
FROM country as c 
  LEFT JOIN citytocountry as cc ON c.idCountry = cc.CountryId
WHERE c.CountryName LIKE 'a%'
GROUP BY c.CountryName
```